# A Python File Runs in IDLE but Not as an EXE

Tags: python, tkinter

So I made this simple script to help me re-share my slide when presenting in Microsoft Teams (I'm a beginner at Python, so sorry if this is trivial) and it works just fine when executing from my IDE (PyCharm if that helps) and in IDLE. However, it simply refuses to work when I compiled it into an exe using pyinstaller. More specifically, it says that the name **quit** is not defined.

Here is the code below:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
import pyautogui as pyg
import time


def reshare():
    pyg.doubleClick(x=1766, y=945)
    pyg.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'e')
    pyg.doubleClick(x=563, y=698)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyg.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'e')
    pyg.doubleClick(x=331, y=696)



root = Tk()
Label1 = Button(root, text="Re-share", command=reshare)
Label2 = Button(root, text="Quit", command=quit)
Label1.pack(side="top")
Label2.pack(side="bottom")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that you don't need to add `<br>`s to your code (and indeed, you shouldn't). Instead, paste your code, then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to indent it so SO formats it as code.

Comment: `quit` is a built-in to quit interpreter, but doesn't work in real programs, only in a REPL see dupe link

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the quick response. I'll go fix it immediately.

Answer (score -1):

Try command = sys.exit instead of command = quit. Add "import sys" at the top.